# How to replace all words with one thing in common in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am writing something with a bunch of information and I have a lot of duplicating words with a certain symbol I was wondering if I could replace all words containing those symbols.

Examples:

```
Bhardwaj
Bhardwaj#930
Torbus
Torbus#931
Reigle
Reigle#932
```

I would like to remove the whole word the ones with numbers, without touching the none numbered words. So the list can look like this.

```
Bhardwaj

Torbus

Reigle
```

Comment: Does notepadd++ support regex search/replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*[^a-zA-Z\r\n].*$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  .*                # 0 or more any character but newline
  [^a-zA-Z\r\n]     # any character that is not alpha or linebreak
  .*                # 0 or more any character but newline
$                   # end of line, you can use \R instead of $ if you want to remove the linebreak.
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, however, it's getting rid of some of the ones without #s..

Comment: @SashaBisset: Are the line you want to remove always containing `#`?

Comment: Yes I do have some lines that have other characters, such as spaces and `·`, I would like to only delete the ones with the name, `#` and the 3 numbers if possible.

Comment: @SashaBisset: Just change `^.*[^a-zA-Z\r\n].*$` to `^.*#\d\d\d$`